# Paring XML loaded by file_get_contents()

Tags: php, xml

I have some simple XML parser

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("xml/UploadTask.xml");

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "item" );
foreach( $items as $item )
{  
  $keys = $item->getElementsByTagName( "key" );
  $key = $keys->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $values = $item->getElementsByTagName( "value" );
  $value = $values->item(0)->nodeValue;

  echo "$key - $value";    
}
```

and it work perfectly for me, how ever if i need to parse XML which comes via POST, my code to load XML looks like (I put it on top of file):

```
$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
echo $xml;
```

and this return XML which comes, everything works right , how ever if I load $xml to DOM (basicly replace 2. line on `$doc->load($xml);`I'm getting no output, no echo of values.

while I try to debug this I notice that if I use file var_dump($items)
i get answer:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

if I do same `var_dump()` with file loaded i get answer:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(2)
}
```

where `int(2)` represent number of matches for this criteria found.

So my question is are there some limits for parsing XML loading with `file_get_contents` ?
and also, is there any workaround on this?

Thanks guys.

Comment: just FYI: `$doc->load('php://input')`  - in addition to the answer. also check the return parameter so you can branch in your code if XML could not be parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DOMDocument::load()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) loads a file (or an URL using the Streamwrappers), not a string. [DOMDocument::loadXml()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) loads a string.

```
$xml = '<foo>Hello World</foo>';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);

var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);
```

Output:

```
string(11) "Hello World"
```

Comment: lol this was simple, I was thinking about some hardcore workarounds :) 
Thanks man
p.s. Will mark this answer as correct as soon as I can